# Verificar se o arquivo foi copiado

Tags: c#

tenho a seguinte situação.

Um arquivo é colocado em um determinado diretório, quando ele for copiado preciso mover o mesmo para outra pasta.

Como faço para verificar se já terminou de colar este arquivo para ser movido depois.

já tenho o método de mover pronto, só preciso verificar se já terminou de copiar no primeiro diretório.

Comment: Comparar o tamanho dele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De a cordo com a resposta do [@dsfgsho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612800/c-sharp-detect-if-file-has-finished-being-written) para uma pergunta parecida com a sua:

Quando um arquivo está sendo usado ele fica indisponível, então você pode verificar a disponibilidade dele e esperar até que fique disponível para uso.

```cs
    void AguardaArquivo()
    {
        // Seu aqruivo
        var file  = new FileInfo("caminho/do/arquivo");

        // Enquanto o arquivo não está acessível, deve estar sendo copiado
        while (IsFileLocked(file)) { }

        // A partir daqui o arquivo está disponível

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Code by ChrisW -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }

        //file is not locked
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou desta maneira